# i need such a thread which can run in background determine the time after every second, in blackberry

Tags: multithreading, blackberry

HI,

i need such a thread which can run in background, determine the time after every second, in blackberry. if any code or link anybody know. plz send it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the following is the code:

```
public class MyApp extends Application
{

public Timer _timer;
public TimerTask _timerTask;


public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    MyApp theApp = new MyApp();       
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}
public MyApp()
{               

    _timer = new Timer();
    _timerTask = new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {
        //Do what u want here   

    }; 
   _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(_timerTask, 0,10000);
}
```

}

Notice that class MyApp is extending Application and not UiApplication,this thing makes this app hidden, if u also want to hide the icon of this app from the Menu  then go to Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml file and check the "Do not Display the Application icon on home screen", And , if you want to auto start this app on Startup check "Auto Start on startup" in same file.